# what is the REST url endpoint standard for download

Tags: rest, url, standards

I know it is HTTP GET rest type to get all or a particular resource details in REST webservices. What if i need to create a rest webservice which downloads a list of employee (filtered by search criteria) details into a file? It must be a GET call but how does the endpoint URL will look like?

```
//baseurl/employee/download?q=searchParam
```

Is this correct way to having my endpoint URL?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "download" ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific 'download' concept in REST. Normally you have a collection resource

```
GET /baseurl/employee
```

that returns a lis of employyes:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "firstName": "Jahn",
    "lastName": "Spencer"
  }
]
```

You can filter this list using a query parameter:

```
GET /baseurl/employee?firstName=John

[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
]
```

That's it. The client can do what he wants with this response.

If the server supports multiple representations like JSON and XML, the client can request the representation he wants.

Comment: the content-type idea is an interesting for being pure-REST but if the client is a web browser, that's not going to work

Comment: with a hyperlink, you can have the browser trigger a download but you can't set the content-type it requests.  with js you can set the content-type but you can't trigger a download

Comment: Looks like we have to wait until the OP tells us what "download" means in his scenario.

Comment: i am assuming it means triggering the browser to save to a local file as you'd expect any 'download' button encountered in an app or on the web to do :)  not sure what else it could possibly mean...

Comment: i have to download this filtered result through a rest call.. how would my rest endpoint would look like